# append input range to body and control video playbackRate javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create and append to the body a range input (slider) with an oninput event listener that controls the video playbackRate, but it is not working...

```
var pitch = document.createElement('input'); 

pitch.setAttibute('type','range');
pitch.setAttibute('min','0');
pitch.setAttibute('max','1'); 
pitch.setAttibute('step','0.01');

document.body.appendChild(pitch); 

var video = document.querySelector('.video-stream');
pitch.oninput = function(){  
    video.playbackRate = pitch.value;
}
```

I have the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: pitch.setAttibute is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you spelled `Attribute` wrong. You spelled it like `setAttibute`, but it really should be `setAttribute`. Fix all the misspellings and your code should work fine